# Why does `cd` command not work via SSH?

Tags: shell, ssh, cd-command

I was trying to backup some files via SSH but instead of `tar`'ing the ones I wanted I got my home folder. I did some further testing and it boils down to this:

```
ssh root@server /bin/sh -c "cd /boot && ls -l"
```

Which to my surprise lists files in **`/root`** not `/boot`. But if I run the entire `/bin/sh` command from a terminal it properly `cd`s and prints the `/boot` files.

What's happening here?

Comment: Unless this is an example, why are you not using `ssh root@server /bin/sh -c "ls -l /boot"`?

Comment: It is funny you asked.  I tried to do that before commenting and still did not get directory listing.

Comment: @demure because I really wanted tar, and tar /boot will include the boot path in the result, which I do not want

Answer (score 44, accepted):

ssh doesn't let you specify a command precisely, as you have done, as a series of arguments to be passed to execvp on the remote host. Instead it concatenates all the arguments into a string and runs them through a remote shell. This stands out as a major design flaw in ssh in my opinion... it's a well-behaved unix tool in most ways, but when it comes time to specify a command it chose to use a single monolithic string instead of an argv, like it was designed for MSDOS or something!

Since ssh will pass your command as a single string to `sh -c`, you don't need to provide your own `sh -c`. When you do, the result is

```
sh -c '/bin/sh -c cd /boot && ls -l'
```

with the original quoting lost. So the commands separated by the `&&` are:

```
`/bin/sh -c cd /boot`
`ls -l`
```

The first of those runs a shell with the command text "cd" and `$0`=`"boot"`. The "cd" command completes successfully, the `$0` is irrelevant, and the `/bin/sh -c` indicates success, then the `ls -l` happens.

Comment: While I agree it's unfortunate that `ssh` behave like that, if it weren't, it would have to be called `sexec`, not `ssh`. `ssh` is the secure version of `rsh` (which behaved the same in that regard) and `rlogin` (`rsh` called `rlogin` when not passed a command line). It's just unfortunate that it doesn't implement `rexec` as well.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas was there ever a rexec command? It's just a C library function as far as I know. Good point though, about rsh. Being a drop-in replacement for rsh was the key to quick adoption in the early days of ssh, when everybody had tons of scripts already using rsh.

Comment: I definitely used it in the past. Looking now, it must have been on HPUX as not many other Unices seem to have it, I have to admit though I was under the impression it was more widespread.

Comment: Thanks.  This really helped, esp. since I'm tunneling with ssh.  I had to do ssh -t machine1 'ssh -t machine2 "echo \"1 && 2\""' to get '1 && 2' as the output.  That killed a few hours.

Comment: If you do want to pass a command precisely, e.g. from "$@", you can use this: `"\`printf "%q " "$@"\`"` with bash's `printf` to quote a string or strings with shell escapes.

Comment: Thank you, this was my problem too, just under Windows. Looks like Bitvise SSH Server prepends its own "CMD /C" shell, so my invocation of the same got resulted in a subshell being called where my CD command had executed successfully without influencing the outer shell where the next command ran in the initial directory.

Answer (score 38):

İt's a quoting issue. Ssh already runs the command you pass it in a shell. When you pass multiple parameters, they are concatenated with a space in between to build a string. So the remote command that you are running remotely is `/bin/sh -c cd /boot && ls -l` (no quotes, because the quotes in your command were interpreted by the local shell).

`/bin/sh -c cd /boot` runs `/bin/sh` and tells it to run the command `cd` and also to set `$0` to `/boot`. Once this is done, the parent shell (the one launched by `sshd`) runs `ls -l`.

In your case, just remove the `sh -c` which is completely useless unless your remote shell (as indicated in `/etc/passwd` or other password database) does not understand this command.

```
ssh root@server "cd /boot && ls -l"
```

If you need to invoke a different shell, you must quote the remote command to protect it from expansion by the remote shell invoked by `sshd`. For example, if your login shell is dash and you want to run a bash command:

```
ssh root@server 'bash -c "cd ~bob && ls -l"'
```

Answer (score 10):

I think it has more to do with how the options are getting parsed by the shell. For example, this works:

```
$ ssh root@server /bin/sh -c '"cd /boot && ls -l"'
```

This has the same issue as your command:

```
$ ssh root@server /bin/sh -c 'cd /boot && ls -l'
```

If you enable the `-v` switch to `ssh` you can see what's going on:

1st command:

> debug1: Sending command: /bin/sh -c "cd /boot && ls -l"

2nd command:

> debug1: Sending command: /bin/sh -c cd /boot && ls -l

Typically when sending commands through `ssh` you have to pay special attention to the quoting and wrap quotes within quotes as the various layers strip them away. Also don't bother sending `/bin/sh`.

You can do very useful thing once you understand the quoting of `ssh` such as the following. This will run the command on the remote server but collect the results in a file locally on the system where you ran the `ssh` command:

```
$ ssh root@server 'free -m' > /tmp/memory.status
```

or this, where you tar a directory on a remote server and create it on the local system:

```
$ ssh remotehost 'tar zcvf - SOURCEDIR' | cat > DESTFILE.tar.gz
```

#### References

- [Pushing & Pulling Files Around Using tar, ssh, scp, & rsync](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/1766/pushing-pulling-files-around-using-tar-ssh-scp-rsync/)

Answer (score 6):

Typically you don't have to specify what shell to use. This works:

```
ssh user@host "cd /boot && pwd"
```

But if your default shell is problematic, then just make sure you quote the **entire** command, including the shell invocation. Either of the following works

```
ssh user@host '/bin/sh -c "cd /boot && pwd"'
ssh user@host "/bin/sh -c \"cd /boot && pwd\""
```

Comment: Note that while `cd /boot && pwd` works in all shells of the major families (Bourne, csh, rc), `/bin/sh -c "cd /boot && pwd"` would not work if the remote shell is of the `rc` family where `"` is not special.